# How can I fix the formatting of my axis using pgfplots so the axis titles aren't on top of the numbers?

Tags: pgfplots, formatting

How can I offset my ylabel so it doesn't smudge with the numbers?

[image]

code

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    scale=1.8,
    xmin=-15,xmax=15,xlabel={Current $mA$}, ylabel={Residuals $mV$}
]
\addplot [only marks, black, error bars/.cd, y dir=both, x dir=both, y explicit, x explicit, error bar style={color=mapped color}]
      table[x=Residuals,y=Voltage,x error=xerr,y error=yerr]{sfnErr.dat}; % plot the data
\draw[ultra thin,gray] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) -- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0); 

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{*}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Use some thing like: `\pgfplotsset{every axis y label/.append style={xshift=1.5em}
}` Adjust the distance as suitable.

Comment: Where to put it? In the preamble?

Comment: If you want it for all graphs, put it in the preamble. If only for one graph, put it as an option to your `\begin{axis}[every axis y label/.append style={xshift=1.5em}]`

Comment: It would be easier to help if you provide an MWE and your or a portion of your `sfnErr.dat`.

Comment: Do you want to get rid of the scaling of the tick labels (so you'd have 0.002 instead of 2.0 * 10^(-3))? Then see [How do you remove the axis multiplier?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9803/how-do-you-remove-the-axis-multiplier). Or do you want to transform your ticks to kHz? Then see [pgfplots exponent in ylabel instead of yticklabel](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74514/pgfplots-exponent-in-ylabel-instead-of-yticklabel)

Comment: In general, it's best to have only one issue per question, and to make some effort to make it more generally applicable. Instead of a title like "How can I fix the formatting of my axis", which doesn't really say much about the actual problem and thus is unlikely to help others with similar issues, break it down to something like "How do I remove the axis multiplier"/"How can I adjust the position of the xlabel"/"How can I increase the number of ticks" and make small compilable example documents.

Comment: @jake yes I agree. Too many people edit questions and forget about the title. It's why I can never find things. I will make this a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you insert `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}` (or whatever your PGFPlots version number is, as long as it's newer than `1.3`) into your preamble, the axis labels will be placed dynamically, taking into account the width of the tick labels.

Comment: How do you check what version you have?

Comment: It's listed in the `.log` file that is generated when you compile your document.

Comment: Thanks for your help @jake I have added some other stuff to elaborate on some additional axis formatting problems. I can verify that your solution did work on my question before I edited. If mods want me to accept this and start a new questin with additional queries I am happy to do so though.